# MySQL Simple Where Clause Not Working in Equal Sign But in Like

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using `SELECT` query in this, the `WHERE` clause doesn't working. 
Query is:

```
SELECT * FROM table_t WHERE id = '96'
```

This query is resulting 0 rows but when  I try:

```
SELECT * FROM table_t WHERE id LIKE '96'
```

This query is working fine and when I try `LIKE` with column name like:

```
SELECT id FROM table_t WHERE id LIKE '96'
```

Returning 0 rows.

The id is auto generated primary key not have white spaces.

Why? Is there any database issue?
This query is working fine on my local machine but when I try it online it is misbehaving.

Thanks.

Comment: What type is `id` column? If it's an integer - you should not put quotes there, just `id = 96`

Answer (score -1):

Your id Field is of integer type and you are trying to compare it with String operator like.Remove quotes from your comparing data ie, 96 In your table it is integer but When you give it within quotes it becomes String and misbehave

Comment: Dear Jerin J,

When I'm trying to delete the record in SQLYog manuallyit is not be deleted.  I think SQLYog at back end using '=' to delete.

This were working fine before and my application were working fine but now this is missbehaving. can you suggest me to down load the whole data base backup, delete it from server and create with the same name and import downloaded database it may work fine.